# Finding the apiVersion for EKS in a region

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

I am learning EKS -- and have been provided the following example YAML to create cluster.

Where does the 'apiVersion' in the example YAML derived from? Is it eksctl or eks?

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: my-demo-cluster
  region: us-west-2
nodeGroups:
  - name: my-demo-workers
    instanceType: t3.medium
    desiredCapacity: 4
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard approach to version API, and here it's definitely coming from `eksctl`: https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/tree/master/pkg/apis/eksctl.io